# Testing a typescript function with a subscribe in it

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I'm testing with Jasmine/Karma and am using Angular 4. I'm trying to test a function that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, this.name assignment is not getting touched. I've tried testing with:

```
it('should make sure name is set', () => {
  component.retrievePageInfo();
  expect(component.name).toBeDefined();
});
```

but it's undefined at this time. I'm not sure how to wait for it to finish.
I've also tried:

```
it('should make sure name is set', () => {
  component.retrievePageInfo().subscribe(art => {
    expect(component.name).toBe(art["name"]);
  });
});
```

But I get the error "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'." But if I change the function to:

```
retrievePageInfo() {
  return this.httpClient.get("/api/art/" + this.art_id)
  .subscribe(art => {
    this.name = art['name'];
  });
}
```

I get the error "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'." but I need the subscribe here.

Help, please!

Edit: A rough example would be nice because I just can't seem to get this right. I'm currently trying to split this into a function that returns an observable and another that uses it, but my tests still aren't catching it

Edit: Here's my newest attempt:
I've imported fakeAsync and tick

```
it('should set name value', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(component.name).toBeUndefined();
    spyOn(component, "retrievePageInfo");
    component.retrievePageInfo();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.name).toBeDefined();
}));
```

Yet I still get a failure of "Expected undefined to be defined."

Comment: Usually, calls to `HttpClient` would be held in a separate service. You can then return the `Observable` (instead of the `Subscription`), and subscribe within your component. As it stands, you can call `subscribe` on `retrievePageInfo` because it doesnt return an Observable

Comment: I see. I have no use to create a service here, but I suppose I could break this down into two functions anyways and I think that would solve my problem then. Yeah?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at async unit testing:

```
 it('#getObservableValue should return value from observable',
    (done: DoneFn) => {
    service.getObservableValue().subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toBe('observable value');
      done();
    });
  });
```

The code above is from the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

Comment: Do you have an example of how to  do this when I'm not returning an observable? .subscribe will not work when I'm doing the subscribe in the function already @danday74